# How can I implement appending new item in an item list dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one form in view for the `@item_list`:

```
<%= form_for @item_list do |f|%>
   some meta-info to describe item_list
<%end%>
```

and also I have a render partial called `_item.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @item_list.item do |f|%>
   some meta-info to describe item_list.item
<%end%>
```

In my index view, I have a button called `add item`, which will call a jquery ajax function to append this partial to a div block, and another button called `done`, which I expect to store all the info in all the forms at one time.

When I try to save these, the parameter doesn't include the item information. I guess that is because I didn't update the `item_list` at the backend when I tried to add a new item. I hope you can provide me some ideas on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to setup a nested form for this. There are many other questions on stackoverflow about nested forms, but here's the gist:

- Create a new empty object in your controller to populate an item `@item_list.items.build` assuming an ItemList has_many Items
- Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :item` in your Item model
- Add `attr_accessible :items_attributes` in your Item model as well
- You're going to need to pass your form builder to the partial, so something like this:

  ```
  _form.html.erb

  <%= form_for @item_list do |f| %>
    <% @item_list.items.each do |item| %>
       <%= render 'item', :f => f %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  _item.html.erb

  <%= f.fields_for :items, item do |item_form| %>
      <%= item_form.text_field ... %>
  <% end %>
  ```

If you need more specifics, please provide us with some more code, including your models with relationships. I'll leave the javascript to you at this point.

Comment: Hi agmin, what I actually wanna do is separate them into different forms. Are there some way I can achieve this?

Comment: If you have separate forms, you can only submit them individually. You could do some javascript hackery to read and then post parameters from all your other forms when one is submitted, but I don't think that makes sense. It still seems like you have a very solid use-case for a nested form, but perhaps you want to ajaxify it to add items?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If I post every forms once I submit, that's probably make the code ugly, and hard to maintain. And I do use ajax to add item. I have already implemented that part. The reason I wanna use multiple form is because The UI, I want to put item list info and the items to two different <div> in one page. so I will keep thinking an efficient way to solve that.

Comment: Thank you agmin, I have rewrite the UI, so that the nested form works very good for that. Thank you for the answer and suggestion. It is helped a lot.